# Tensorflow broadcastable shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm fitting this neural network with `Tensorflow 2.10.1` but I get an error when using the last batch that has a smaller size `[22, 40, 40, 1]` than the others `[32, 40, 40, 1]`

The network is defined as

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import ELU, PReLU, LeakyReLU
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Dense, Input, Reshape, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K

tf.random.set_seed(1234)
eps0 = tf.random.normal(shape=(3000, z_dim), seed=66)     # make model deterministic

class CVAE(tf.keras.Model):
    """Convolutional variational autoencoder."""
    def __init__(self, z_dim, input_shape=(40, 40, 1), deterministic=False):
        super(CVAE, self).__init__()
        self.deterministic = deterministic
        self.z_dim = z_dim
        weight_init = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=42)
        # define encoder
        encoder_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
        en_conv1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(encoder_input)
        en_conv1 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(en_conv1)
        
        en_conv2 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(en_conv1)
        en_conv2 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(en_conv2)
        
        en_conv3 = Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(en_conv2)
        en_conv3 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(en_conv3)
        
        #en_conv4 = Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(en_conv3)
        #en_conv4 = LeakyReLU(0.1)(en_conv4)
        
        en_fc1= Flatten()(en_conv3)
        mean = Dense(z_dim, kernel_initializer=weight_init)(en_fc1)
        logvar = Dense(z_dim, kernel_initializer=weight_init)(en_fc1)
        self.encoder = Model(encoder_input,[mean, logvar], name='encoder')
        
        # define decoder
        decoder_input = Input(shape=(z_dim,))
        de_fc2 = Dense(en_conv3.shape[1]*en_conv3.shape[2]*en_conv3.shape[3], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(decoder_input)
        de_fc2 = Reshape((en_conv3.shape[1], en_conv3.shape[2],en_conv3.shape[3]))(de_fc2)
        de_conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(de_fc2)
        de_conv2 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(de_conv1)
        #de_conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(de_conv2)
        decoder_output = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='sigmoid', padding='same', kernel_initializer=weight_init)(de_conv2)
        self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name='decoder')

    @tf.function(reduce_retracing=True)
    def encode(self, x):
        mean, logvar = self.encoder(x)
        return mean, logvar
    
    def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):      # sample latent
        if self.deterministic:
            eps = eps0[:mean.shape[0], :]
        else:
            eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
        return eps * tf.exp(logvar) + mean
    
    def decode(self, z):
        reconstr = self.decoder(z)
        return reconstr

def compute_kernel(x, y):
    x_size = K.shape(x)[0]
    y_size = K.shape(y)[0]
    dim = K.shape(x)[1]
    tiled_x = K.tile(K.reshape(x, [x_size, 1, dim]), [1, y_size, 1])
    tiled_y = K.tile(K.reshape(y, [1, y_size, dim]), [x_size, 1, 1])
    return K.exp(-K.mean(K.square(tiled_x - tiled_y), axis=2) / K.cast(dim, 'float32'))

def compute_mmd(x, y):
    x_kernel = compute_kernel(x, x)
    y_kernel = compute_kernel(y, y)
    xy_kernel = compute_kernel(x, y)
    return K.mean(x_kernel) + K.mean(y_kernel) - 2 * K.mean(xy_kernel)

def compute_loss(model, x, deterministic=False):
    mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
    z_train = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)                              # q(z|x)
    if deterministic:
        sample_latent = eps0[-200:, :]
    else:
        sample_latent = tf.random.normal(tf.stack([200, z_dim]))              # p(z)
    x_reconstr = model.decode(z_train)

    loss_mmd = compute_mmd(sample_latent, z_train)

    loss_rec = K.mean(K.square(x - x_reconstr))

    return loss_mmd, loss_rec

@tf.function(reduce_retracing=True)
def train_step(model, x, optimizer, deterministic=False):
    """Executes one training step and returns the loss.
    
    This function computes the loss and gradients, and uses the latter to
    update the model's parameters.
    """
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_mmd, loss_nll = compute_loss(model, x, deterministic)
        loss = loss_mmd + loss_nll
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    return {'loss_mmd': loss_mmd, 'loss_nll': loss_nll, 'loss': loss}
```

and I get the error when evaluating the loss with

```
batch_size = 32
z_dim = 5
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
deterministic = True
model = CVAE(z_dim, input_shape=(40, 40, 1), deterministic=deterministic)

data_train=np.random.rand(2166, 40, 40, 1)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.convert_to_tensor(data_train, dtype=tf.float32)).batch(batch_size)
for train_x in train_dataset:
    d = train_step(model, train_x, optimizer, deterministic) # <---- works fine if train_x is [32,40,40,1], not if [22,40,40,1]
```

this is the error

```
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3284\424814309.py", line 79, in compute_loss
      z_train = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
    File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3284\424814309.py", line 56, in reparameterize
      return eps * tf.exp(logvar) + mean
Node: 'mul'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node mul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_step_34072]
```

if I run the function outside the `train_step()` everything works fine

```
print(train_x.shape)
mean, logvar = model.encode(train_x)
z_train = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
print(z_train.shape)
```

returns

```
(22, 40, 40, 1)
(22, 25)
```

---

I need to add more text, so discard this part
I need to add more text, so discard this part
I need to add more text, so discard this part
I need to add more text, so discard this part
I need to add more text, so discard this part
I need to add more text, so discard this part

Comment: Can you show your model instance initialization, especially with the `z_dim` parameter?

Comment: @mhenning I updated the code, now is fully reproducible. Thanks!

Comment: The `compute_loss()` function inside the `training_step()` is still missing. If I run the script without the call `d = train_step(model, train_x, optimizer, deterministic)` in the loop, it works without errors, but I think you already mentioned that.

Comment: @mhenning try now

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, I got a different error, but the root of the problem could be the same. My error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "[Filepath to your script].py", line 137, in 
> d = train_step(model, train_x, optimizer, deterministic) # <---- works fine if train_x is [32,40,40,1], not if [22,40,40,1]
> File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
> tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
> Detected at node 'gradient_tape/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
> File "[Filepath to your script].py", line 137, in 
> d = train_step(model, train_x, optimizer, deterministic) # <---- works fine if train_x is [32,40,40,1], not if [22,40,40,1]
> File "[Filepath to your script].py", line 122, in train_step
> gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
> Node: 'gradient_tape/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs'
> **Incompatible shapes: [3000,5] vs. [22,5]**
> [[{{node gradient_tape/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_step_4288]

The problem is this line:

```py
@tf.function(reduce_retracing=True)
def train_step(...) # not this line
```

You can see the effect of `reduce_retracing` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#use_reduce_retracing_for_automatic_flexibility). The shape of x goes to `None` when the shape changes, because TF tries to reduce retracing the shape and just uses a filler `None` value which fits everything. The prolem is that you use this part of the shape in

```py
def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):  # sample latent
    if self.deterministic:
        eps = eps0[:mean.shape[0], :]
    else:
        eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
```

And when the `batch_size` goes to 22, `mean.shape[0]` goes from 32 to None. In the deterministic case, `eps0[:None, :]` returns the full `eps0` array, which explains the shape `(3000,)` in the error message. In the non-deterministic case, the error changes to

> eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
> ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape (None, 5) to a Tensor.

The problem stays the same, `None` in the shape.

The solution is to turn of `reduce_retracing` (`reduce_retracing=False`). Then TF computes actual shapes of batches and there is no error in both cases for me.

The line

> required broadcastable shapes

in your error message could stem from the same problem with `None` values, but it is a bit weird that I got other error messages with the same code piece. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):      # sample latent
    if self.deterministic:
        eps = eps0[:mean.shape[0], :]
    else:
        eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
```

When this function runs inside a graph (i.e., inside a function decorated with [`@tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function), or any code indirectly called from it), static shape is not what you want here. Use the Keras backend function `K.shape()` in both calls, like you do in other places.

The documentation to [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) notes:

> `tf.shape` and `Tensor.shape` should be identical in eager mode. Within `tf.function` or within a `compat.v1` context, not all dimensions may be known until execution time. Hence, when defining custom layers and models for graph mode, prefer the dynamic `tf.shape(x)` over the static `x.shape`.

`keras.backend.shape()` is aware of eager vs. graph differences, and abstracts them out for you.